# Populating a wrapper class with pass-through methods

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I inherited a large rather-old C++98 codebase which is now luckily using C++17. I have an interface in a header file `interfaceHeader.h` as follows:

```cpp
struct PluginInterface {
  void (*method1)(bool enabled);
  void (*method2)(int param1, int param2);
  bool (*method3)(const char *path, const int& val);
};
```

then in another source cpp file:

```cpp
MyImplementingClass *gClass = new gClass();

void method1(bool enabled) {
  gClass->method1(enabled);
}

void method2(int p1, int p2) {
  gClass->method2(p1, p2);
}

bool method3(const char *path, const int& val) {
  return gClass->method3(path, val);
}

void pupulateInterface(PluginInterface& iface) {

    iface.method1 = method1;
    iface.method1 = method2;
    iface.method1 = method3;
    ...
 }
```

I don't have control over that global variable nor on the fact that the interface must be a struct of function pointer.

How can I reduce the boilerplate here? I tried using `std::bind` but it didn't work: a `std::function` cannot be converted to a C function pointer.

Comment: why is this tagged C? What do you mean with "C function pointer" ? Do you just mean a "function pointer" ?

Comment: Please don't tag unrelated languages. If you're programming in C++ then don't add the C language tag.

Comment: in case you use the term "C function pointer" to distinguish from `std::function`, note that `std::function` is not the drop in replacement for function pointers in C++, it is much more than that. Function pointers in C++ are function pointers

Comment: Also, can you modify or change `PluginInterface` in any way? If not, then there's not really much you can do to improve the situation.

Comment: I can modify PluginInterface, but unfortunately it has to be a struct and quite simple (with just a table of pointers)

Comment: I can't even make `std::bind` work if I make all those functions `static`, sigh

Comment: So you can't refactor the structure as `struct PluginInterface { std::function<void(bool)> method1; /* etc... */ };`? The structure must still contain the pointers to the functions?

Comment: And what is this `PluginInterface` structure used for? Can it be inherited? Can it inherit something?

Comment: a free function is fundamenatlly different from a free function with some arguments bound to it. One is just a function the other is a function + data. A function pointer can only be used for functions not for function + data.

Answer (score 0):

```
 void pupulateInterface2(PluginInterface& iface) {

iface.method1 = [](bool enabled){
    gClass->method1(enabled);
};
iface.method2 = [](int param1, int param2){
    gClass->method2(param1,param2);
};
iface.method3 = [](const char *path, const int& val){
    return gClass->method3(path, val);
};
```

}

Comment: how long are these lambda functions going to live exactly? Will they outlive the `populateInterface` function? I don't want to call into undefined behavior

Comment: My understanding is: the lambda will create a class, it overrides operator() and the function pointer convert operator. in the function pointer convert operator, it returns the operator() 's pointer. This lambda captures nothing, it is just like your method pointers just point to some generated functions.